MS Teams : Deep Link Chat
<a type="button" class="border-0 card-link" href='https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users="@poc.SMEContactEmail"&message="Request more info on poc"- @poc.Name'>Chat with SME</a>

When i hover over the button link i am able to see the SMEContactEmail , however when I click on the button teams is open but it is not able to open chat with that email address.
We've started your group chat but couldn't add "
Can anyone advise?
Trying to embed teams link in a table provided with chat option,
It is opening teams but the chat with the person is not opening
We've started your group chat but couldn't add "
